# Is it possible to link Jira cloud and Bitbucket server?

Tags: jira

I want to link Jira hosted in the cloud and Bitbucket server hosted in my private network.

Comment: Yes, you can link jira with bitbucket. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-cloud-applications-814190686.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but there are some restrictions for your local Bitbucket server.

From the [Bitbucket Server documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/linking-bitbucket-server-with-jira-776640408.html#LinkingBitbucketServerwithJIRA-LinkBitbucketServerwithJIRASoftwareCloud):

### Link Bitbucket Server with JIRA Software Cloud

> There are port restrictions, and other considerations, when linking Bitbucket Server with JIRA Software Cloud. 
>   Your local server must use a valid SSL certificate, and it must be accessible on port 80 or 443.
>
> For more information, see this [Atlassian Cloud documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/link-to-server-apps-from-cloud-744721656.html).
>   If you have a internet-facing firewall, make sure to allow the IP range used by Atlassian to reach your internal network. For up-to-date information on that, see [Database and IP information](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/database-and-ip-information-744721662.html).